# Lost config targetcli

Tags: iscsi, targetcli

I have a disc with data and lost targetcli configuration. 
The disk.img exists and has a 900 GB size but I do not have the saveconfig.json configuration file. How to recover or extract the data from disk.img file?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just recreate the format? It should be simple enough to recreate the configuration. Just use the 'fileio' option.

Or you could try loop-mounting the dot-img file. Check out [this link](http://madduck.net/blog/2006.10.20:loop-mounting-partitions-from-a-disk-image/)
(which was found by searching for 'loop mounting a disk image').